# Clean solution to this ruby iterator trickiness?

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator, for-loop, enumerable

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5]
for n in k
  puts n
  if n == 2
    k.delete(n)
  end
end
puts k.join(",")

# Result:
# 1
# 2
# 4
# 5
# [1,3,4,5]

# Desired:
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# [1,3,4,5]
```

This same effect happens with the other array iterator, k.each:

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5]
k.each do |n|
  puts n
  if n == 2
    k.delete(n)
  end
end
puts k.join(",")
```

has the same output.

The reason this is happening is pretty clear...Ruby doesn't actually iterate through the objects stored in the array, but rather just turns it into a pretty array index iterator, starting at index 0 and each time increasing the index until it's over.  But when you delete an item, it still increments the index, so it doesn't evaluate the same index twice, which I want it to.

This *might* not be what's happening, but it's the best I can think of.

Is there a clean way to do this?  Is there already a built-in iterator that can do this?  Or will I have to dirty it up and do an array index iterator, and not increment when the item is deleted? (or iterate through a clone of the array, and delete from the original array)

---

**Clarification**

I don't simply want to delete items from an array; sorry if that was clear.  What I'd want to do is iterate through each element, and "process" it; this process might sometimes delete it.  To be more accurate:

```
class Living_Thing

  def initialize tracker,id
    @tracker = tracker
    @id = id

    @tracker << self
  end

  def process
    do_stuff
    puts @id
    if @id == 2
      die
    end
  end

  def die
    do_stuff_to_die
    @tracker.delete(self)
  end

  def inspect
    @id
  end
end

tracking_array = Array.new()

foo = Living_Thing.new(tracking_array,1)
bar = Living_Thing.new(tracking_array,2)
rab = Living_Thing.new(tracking_array,3)
oof = Living_Thing.new(tracking_array,4)

puts tracking_array.join(",")              # => [1, 2, 3, 4]

for n in tracking_array
  n.process
end

# result: only foo, bar, and oof are processed
```

Ideally, I'd want all items in tracking_array to be processed.

When Living_Thing is removed from tracking_array, Living_Thing#die *must* be called; do_stuff_to_die cleans up things that have to be claned up.

Comment: is this for a Rails application or just Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this might be more suited for the processing (Ref. updated clarification)

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5] 
k.dup.each do |n| 
  puts n 
  if n == 2
    k.delete(n) 
  end 
end 
puts k.join(",")
```

it side steps the question you had though (about iteration through objects vs iteration through indices)

Comment: thanks; i hadn't thought of using k.dup with .each in one line, instead of using a temp variable; this is the solution i'll be using for now...although, yeah, it does side-step the actual iteration deletion question.

Answer (score 15):

It's an error in most languages to mutate a collection while you're iterating it. In most languages the solution is to create a copy and mutate that or build up a list of indexes and perform the operations on those indexes when you're done iterating, but Ruby's iterators give you a bit more than that. A couple of solutions are obvious. The most idiomatic IMO:

```
puts k
puts k.reject {|n| n == 2}.join(',')
```

More directly translated from your example:

```
k.delete_if do |n|
  puts n
  n == 2
end
puts k.join(',')
```

(`delete_if` is basically the destructive version of `reject`, which returns an array of the objects that the block did not return true for.)

Comment: nice, I like delete_if very clean solution

Comment: Using delete_if to run a full code block for every item is pretty elegant; I like it a lot =)  I'll be sure to keep it in my arsenal; however, for my current problem, it doesn't quite work =/

Comment: Or use `reject!` which is equivalent to `delete_if`.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so let's say you want to eliminate all 2's from your array:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.delete(2)
puts arr.join(", ")
# => "1, 3, 4, 5"
arr = [1,2,3,2,4,2,5,2]
arr.delete(2)
puts arr.join(", ")
# => "1, 3, 4, 5"
```

But I suspect you want to iterate, so I would:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.each {|x| a[a.index(x)] = nil if x == 2}.compact!
```

Maybe that's too dirty? The assignment to nil keeps the iterator count right, and the `compact!` wipes out the nils after the fact. Course `map` keeps it a little shorter and is cleaner:

```
arr.map {|x| x if x != 2}.compact!
```